# How to turn off "errorabend" in SAS permanently?

Tags: sas

It is too annoying that SAS is shut down every time a little bug is detected. Can anyone tell me how to turn off the errorabend option permanently (globally)? Thanks!

Comment: Wow. I hope you're not working on anything important.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can go to your configuration file and specify `NOERRORABEND` there or in the code itself in the `option` you can write `NOERRORABEND`

Whichever works for you!

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000279092.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've already used "option noerrorabend" in my code but the problem is every time I run a part of the code I need to include this line. Could you tell me how to locate the configuration file and make the adjustment there? And normally is "noerrorabend" set as default by SAS? Thank you!